# Keycloak: Subscribe events like create user to trigger a webservice

Tags: java, events, keycloak, keycloak-services

I need to update from the Keycloak to another proprietary data store information about created users (no matter if created directly in Keycloak or in a connected LDAP/Active directory).
I tried to enhance the logging but it seems that this is not logging everything.

Is there a way in Keycloak to subscribe to some events (like create user) and trigger some logging / web Service call from that event – so that all information are transmitted?
What would be the right point to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can write your own Event Listener by implementing the EventListenerProvider and EventListenerProviderFactory interfaces, more can found in [server development](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_events) documentation.

You can also find sample event listener that writes events to System.out in [keycloak-quickstarts](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/event-listener-sysout)

Comment: That looks promising - Works with accessing local users (form session) has to be verified if federated users work as well. Next problem would be to send a web-request form within the plugin without pulling external dependencies.